I cannot add an Image in my Website's Metadata
Here is what my website looks like on google:
Image
I would like to add my logo. I have tried adding my logo to my page's metadata like this, but it's not showing up.
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "CardCounter - Learn Blackjack and Card Counting",
  description:
    "Unlock the secrets of card counting with CardCounter. Master advanced blackjack strategies, boost your edge over the house, and start winning consistently! Whether you're a beginner or an experienced player, our expert card counting tips and blackjack tutorials will help you master the game. Learn to count cards, optimize your gameplay, and improve your odds at the table.",
  keywords:
    "Blackjack, card counting, learn blackjack, advanced card counting, card counting strategies, blackjack training, basic strategy, expert card counting tips, master blackjack",
  openGraph: {
    title: "CardCounter - Learn Blackjack and Card Counting",
    description:
      "Unlock the secrets of card counting with CardCounter. Master advanced blackjack strategies, boost your edge over the house, and start winning consistently! Learn expert tips and improve your odds.",
    url: "https://www.cardcounter21.com/home",
    images: [
      {
        url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Card-counter-logo.png",
        alt: "CardCounter Logo",
      },
    ],
  },
  robots: {
    index: true,
    follow: true,
  },
  alternates: {
    canonical: "https://www.cardcounter21.com/home",
  },
};

I would appreciate if someone can tell mw how to add my logo so it appears when someone searches up my website.
Thank you!

what you're looking for is a favicon.ico, all you need to do is use a .ico file that has a size of 16x16 pixels, its name has to be favicon so that it can be found during build or development, you need to add this file in the app directory (same level as the root layout if there are no route groups)
